# What does "vile doth deny" mean?

Tags: meaning

A group of painters are enjoying drinks and saw Vincent
drawing something:

> Henri: Lei me finish it in a minute for him.
>
> MAN: You're being vile.
>
> Henri: **The vile doth deny**.

What does "vile doth deny" mean?

Comment: Do you know the meaning of the word "vile",  "doth" and "deny" ?  If so can you add those meanings to your question?

Comment: The vile [person] doth deny. Like *The Good, the Bad and the Ugly*.